# scipy install on linux: can't find a lapack object sgges_

Tags: python, installation, scipy, lapack

I am trying to install scipy, and encountering problems.  Comparing my
results to the FAQ page, it looks like my ATLAS is incomplete.  The page
says:

LAPACK library provided by ATLAS is incomplete
You will notice it when getting import errors like 
ImportError: .../flapack.so : undefined symbol: sgesdd_
To be sure that NumPy/SciPy is built against a complete LAPACK, check the
size of the file liblapack.a - it should be about 6MB. The location of
liblapack.a is shown by executing 
python numpy/distutils/system_info.py lapack
To fix: follow the instructions in
http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/errata.html#completelp Building a
complete LAPACK library to create a complete liblapack.a. Then copy
liblapack.a to the same location where libatlas.a is installed and retry
with scipy build.

The actual object I am missing is "sgges_".  I have tried two solutions.

1) I have followed the ATLAS instructions for making a complete build of
LAPACK, rev. 3.4.2.  (BTW, the resulting LAPACK is about 10MB, bigger than
the 6MB in the FAQ.)

2) I have found a pre-compiled binary for LAPACK - rev. unclear -- and just
downloaded it and dropped it in place.  (It is close to the 6MB in size.)

I get the same problem regardless.

"nm" shows sgges_ defined in liblapack.a plain as day.  System_info.py finds my lapack just fine in /usr/local/lib.

Is this a critical failure?  Is there anything else to do?

BTW, I am running python 2.7 on a 64 bit CentOs 5.x machine and gfortran is
my FORTRAN compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting up LAPACK + ATLAS according to the following guides: http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/03/compiling-lapack-on-centos-5.html http://linuxcluster.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/compiling-atlas-on-centos5/

Answer (score 1):

I had to complile scipy from scratch on a slackware 13 linux distribution which is a very basic linux system;  I listed out all the steps and results here:

[SCIPY install from source code on slackware 13](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/slackware-linux/179312-scipy-numpy-install-slackware-13-a.html)

In my install, I was trying to get the dynamic libraries to install in a local directory /home/andrew3/.local/lib  because it wasn't a system install.  Similar errors to what you are encountering were caused by the linker ldd not being able to find the libraries.

You might be able to isolate your problem by replicating my steps, and seeing where it fails if anyplace.